# Informatica XML generator is appending zeros for double fields even after setting scale to zero

Tags: informatica-powercenter

XML generator is appending zeros for double fields even after setting scale to zero.

I exported the whole mapping updated the scale to 0 for doubles which were troubling, but the generated XML still contains the zeros appended to them.

Comment: Could you please add some more info on this topic, perhaps try the two suggestions below and tell us what you see ?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are NOT running the session in 'High precision' mode ?
That causes the engine to treat all decimal numbers as 'double' which used to perform much better before version 7'ish, but may cause errors like this.

Another guess:
Did you forget to change the output format in your flat file target?

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a definite answer instead of a guess, including what exactly one has to do to fix the problem in question and why. You can [edit] your answer to improve it.

Comment: I agree, but unless I'm provided with more information, guessing is the best I can do :) basically any of the two possibilities can give a result that matches the description

Comment: If there is not enough information in the question, don't write an answer, but ask for clarification in a comment and/or flag to close if the question is not answerable in its current state.

Comment: Will do :) - I weren't able to add comments yesterday - only 'answers' which seems odd....

Comment: That's because you only reached 50 reputation yesterday. With less than 50 rep, you can only comment on your own content. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges